# How can I exit a quest?

Tags: infinity-blade-3

I was upgrading my main weapon, when I started a quest and realized I only had the starter weapon and could not complete the quest. How can I exit the quest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to options > advanced options, you can choose to reset from last awakening which should bring you back to the island camp.

Alternatively you could die 2 times to an enemy and you should get the same option to reset to last awakening. Since there is no penalty for dying in normal gameplay, you could use this option if you wanted to at least attempt some fights before deciding to exit.

Note that with both options you will keep all progress such as items, gold, xp etc. but the game will be slightly easier since it is tuned to a lower awakening

Comment: I looked in the advanced options, and it wasn't there, and I also have gotten killed by the same thing over 2 times, and I still can't restart.